# making a search under this coding process

Tags: php, mysql

this codes below came from my friend. i want to make a search under this codes . from this codes , it will display all the users to delete. what i want is i want to put search box and search button . so when i insert user id and press search only then it display which user that i want . where should i put this search text , button and php ? i want to put it under this else if codes . help me. im new :(

```
else if($_SESSION['jawatan'] == 'ADMIN') { ?>
      <li> <a href="view.php">VIEW PROFILE</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="request.php">VIEW REQUEST</a> </li>
      <li><a href="logout.php">LOG OUT</a></li>
      <li><img src="msc.jpg" width = "240" height ="80"></li>

      <form method="get">
           <input type="text" name="userid" placeholder="search" />
           <inpu type="submit" value="Search" />
      </form>

      <h3>View User</h3>
      <table border='1'>
        <tr> 
          <td><b>#</b></td>
          <td><b>Nama</b></td>
          <td><b>Email</b></td>
          <td><b>Division</b></td>
          <td><b>Department</b></td>
          <td><b>Delete</b></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $i = 1;

        $whr="";

        if(isset($_GET['userid'])){
           $whr.= " and mem_id='".$_GET['userid']."'"; // which field you want. If you want to do search name use LIKE instead =(equal to)
        }

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE mem_role='USER' ".$whr);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
         ?>
        <tr> 
          <td> 
            <?php echo $i; ?>
          </td>
          <td> 
            <?php echo $row['mem_name']; ?>
          </td>
          <td> 
            <?php echo $row['mem_email']; ?>
          </td>
          <td> 
            <?php echo $row['mem_division']; ?>
          </td>
          <td> 
            <?php echo $row['mem_department']; ?>
          </td>
          <td><a href="delete.php?var1=admin&var2=<?php echo $row['mem_id'];?>">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $i++;
        }
      } else {
        echo '<tr><td>No results found</td></tr>';
      }
        ?>
      </table>
      <?php
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<form method="get">
     <input type="text" name="userid" placeholder="search" />
     <inpu type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
$whr="";

if(isset($_GET['userid'])){
   $whr.= " and mem_id='".$_GET['userid']."'"; // which field you want. If you want to do search name use LIKE instead =(equal to)
}
```

MYSQL

```
$result = $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE mem_role='USER' ".$whr);// add whr variable here
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\senyum\view.php on line 156 hm i already edit the codes. could u check for me ? sorry im new

Comment: i already send u the code. the edit one. this under admin . actually i was making under 3 user. super admin , admin, and user.  i want make search under admin . thats all in admin . i want to make form and php under admin . can u check it for me ? did i declare code u give correctly?

Comment: <form> u placed is okay. but the PHP code u wrongly placed.

Comment: could u change it for me ? sorry im new. can you send me the coding ?

Comment: i already use your code. but it found one user only. when i enter another user , it display result not found.

Comment: nevermind. i already got it. thank you so much :) really help it.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you the steps:

- Create search text field and search button ( wrap in form if you want to do with php only)
- on click of button ( that would be submit ), fetch that value from search text box and run query based on that
- when results appear , fill the table data with that results using `foreach`.

hope it helps. Ask me for any issue.